# How do you get rosegarden to play sound when playing a midi in it?

Tags: 14.04, sound, jack, midi, rosegarden

How do you get rosegarden to play sound when playing a midi in it? Do I need Jack running?

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to have Jack running in order to playback MIDIs with Rosegarden.

What I now have running is MIDI file playback via Rosegarden and QSynth.

The process as of Ubuntu 17.10 is largely the same [as here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/setting-up-rosegarden-for-midi-music-in-linux-ubuntu-8-04-a-697198/), but follow these steps:

- install QSynth `apt-get install fluidsynth`
- install a soundfont library `apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gs`
- configure QSynth to `Enable MIDI Input` by checking the box in `Setup > MIDI`
- configure QSynth to use `alsa` Audio Driver under `Setup > Audio`
- configure QSynth to use the soundfont under `Setup > Soundfonts`; point to `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2` or your soundfont location
- allow QSynth to restart when it prompts you
- install Rosegarden `apt-get install rosegarden`
- with QSynth open, launch Rosegarden
- Tell Rosegarden to play through QSynth `Studio > Manage MIDI Devices` and set the `General MIDI Device` to whatever QSynth broadcasts as its MIDI input option, ie `129:0 Synth input port` or similar.

Comment: Thank you ,that worked very well, except that whenever I open a new song I have to do, again, the step "Tell Rosegarden to play through QSynth Studio > Manage MIDI Devices and set the General MIDI Device to whatever QSynth broadcasts as its MIDI input option, ie 129:0 Synth input port or similar.". I wish this step just remained saved.

Comment: Doesn't work (no sound)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/tour/synths/) says:

> Rosegarden includes synth plugin support for sample-accurate synthesis of MIDI tracks.
>   […]
>   And as well as plugins, Rosegarden can communicate with any number of standalone soft synths for Linux using the ALSA sequencer MIDI protocol.

Synth plugins usually are very specialized; if you want to play some random MIDI file, you probably need a general-puporse software synthesizer like Fluidsynth or Timidity.

Comment: I have fluidity.

Comment: [Not a synthesizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidity).

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the Rosegarden+Qsynth answer to work without having to open 2 different windows, as follows:

1. Install `fluidsynth` and `rosegarden`, as well as the corresponding soundfonts via `apt`
2. Add the following function to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`:

```bsh
midy() {
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  rosegarden "$1" &
else
  rosegarden &
fi
fluidsynth -a alsa -m alsa_seq -o midi.autoconnect=True <PATH_TO_YOUR_SF2_FILE>
}
```

3. Open a new terminal: type `midy` and load a MIDI file, or `midy <PATH_TO_MIDI_FILE>`, and hit play: `rosegarden` should open, and `fluidsynth` should play the file in the background, without the need of a Qsynth window!

### Notes:

- To test that `fluidsynth` is working, you can try the corresponding command (after the `fi`) separately, by adding the path to the MIDI file at the end. It should play the file.
- In my case the `.sf2` files were installed under `/usr/share/sounds/sf2`
- You can find further options by checking `man fluidsynth` and `fluidsynth -o help`

Hope this helps! Cheers
Andres